# How to incrementally load data in mvccontrib grid in Asp.Net MVC2

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, mvccontrib-grid

I have a large data set and I want to load it incrementally so the user will have faster view loading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could implement pagination (using the `AsPagination` extension method from the `MvcContrib.Pagination` namespace):

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    IEnumerable<MyViewModel> model = ... fetch from somewhere the dataset
    return View(model.AsPagination(1, 10));
}
```

and in your view:

```
@model IPagination<MyViewModel>
@(Html
    .Grid<MyViewModel>(Model)
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.For(x => x.Id);
        columns.For(x => x.Name);
    })
)
@Html.Pager(Model)
```

[The documentation](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Grid) contains examples.

Comment: dimitrov it pages automatically how can custom paginate mvccontrib grid. like by default it should load only first page but show no of pages.Later as the person clicks it should load accordingly

Comment: @Amritpal Singh, in your controller action you could use the `.AsPaginate` extension method on your `IEnumerable<T>` which will automatically return an instance of `IPagination<T>` and then you will bind to this instance instead of the original dataset.

Comment: I am using MVC2 I didnot find ASPagination method

Answer (score 0):

Or do it in Twitter way - get another portion when user scroll to the end of the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax for loading the data as Dima metioned.
If your user experience is extremely important, you may need to load 2 or 3 portions more. For example, the page loads the first two portions, and then loads next two portions when the user scrolls the end of portion 1. This could make the experience more smoother.

Comment: that i know what i have to do but i don't know how to do it using mvccontrib grid?